# How do we filter the encoded special character in sql query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have tried this way, but it's not working--

```
select * from commerce.PhaseDetail where ShortDescription like '%�%'
```

Example string: `Epson Somerset Velvet Fine Art Matte Inkjet Paper, 19 mil., 255 g/m��., 24`

Comment: Are those squares really exist in data? Looks like it is just unable to print them or they are in different codepage (so the text is already broken)

Comment: Try `where shortdescription regexp '[^\x00-\x7F]'`. That should return all instances where that column contains a non-ascii characters.  Don't have access to MySQL currently, so can't promise it'll work.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. It's not an original character. It looks like an unencoded character, formatted by an SQL server.

Comment: That looks like the [Replacement character](https://codepoints.net/U+FFFD) that I believe is used when the character set doesn't understand the particular encoded character. What is the character set used in your database? If I was to guess, the m�� is probably m-cubed, as in m³ or similar. (Though ³ in particular is only actually one character, so I'm guessing it's more the "similar" than this character).